# How do I interpolate a time series, when measurements are taken at irregular times

Tags: pandas

Assume the following data frame:

```
                        values
2019-01-01 00:01:56   0.149511
2019-01-01 00:03:54   0.608400
2019-01-01 00:05:48   1.345600
2019-01-01 00:08:54   3.168400
2019-01-01 00:11:59   5.744011
2019-01-01 00:14:30   8.410000
2019-01-01 00:17:39  12.460900
2019-01-01 00:20:04  16.106844
2019-01-01 00:23:02  21.221378
2019-01-01 00:25:14  25.468844
2019-01-01 00:28:33  32.604100
2019-01-01 00:30:17  36.683211
2019-01-01 00:33:14  44.178178
2019-01-01 00:35:26  50.220844
2019-01-01 00:38:10  58.267778
2019-01-01 00:40:23  65.232544
2019-01-01 00:42:22  71.797378
2019-01-01 00:44:30  79.210000
2019-01-01 00:46:14  85.500844
2019-01-01 00:48:23  93.637878
```

As you can see, the index are random times (between 100 to 200 seconds apart). I would like to get a data frame with the interpolated value, at specific frequency (e.g. every 5 minutes, with the index running on `[00:00:00, 00:05:00, 00:10:00 ... 00:55:00]`, etc.), and the values of course interpolated with some specific method (cubic, linear, etc.).

Comment: How about resampling first?

Comment: Please elaborate, because I'm a little bit lost. When trying relampling, I'm getting all values are NaN, as there are no datapoints on the 5, 10, 15 minutes. Or maybe (very likely) I'm missing something. @MarkWang

Comment: resample at 1s, df.resample('1s').asfreq(). interpolate after that. take index every 5 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data.resample('1s').asfreq().interpolate().resample('5min').last()
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark Wang. And the answer fits my current need. However, I wander what should I do when the timeline index spanning over several years, while the granularity is second. e.g. (2015-01-01 00:00:01, 2016-02-02 00:00:02, etc.), while the desired time series is also once a year. That's many seconds to up-sample and interpolate, just to take few data points.

Comment: @Uri try this `data.append(data.resample('5min').asfreq()).sort_index().interpolate(method='index').resample('5min').last()`

Comment: also, consider to modify your answer to 'first()' for the down sampling.   I believe this is the correct algorithm.